# Use of currency symbols along with a thousand separator

Tags: units

I frequently use the `eurosym` package to typeset Euro values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}    
\EUR{100000}
\end{document}
```

This translates into '€ 100000'.

It however misses the option for thousands separators. For an English text, I'd like to convert this into '€ 100,000'. In a German text, one would rather do '100.000 €'. The placement of the Euro sign is already taken care of by the eurosym package.

Is there a way (ideally, a package) that provides this or does someone have an idea how to achieve this easily?

Comment: Have you had a look at the `siunitx` package? It can also handle currency with a special syntax. And includes various tools to format numbers

Comment: Not yet, I'll check that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the same `eurosym` package along with `sistyle` package in which you define the separator location to be thousand using `SIthousandsep{,}`. Then you can use this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{sistyle}
\SIthousandsep{,}
\newcommand{\euros}[1]{\euro{\num{#1}}}

\begin{document}
I have a 5-figure pay check with \euros{40000}.

Now I am a millionaire with \euros{4000000}.

I wish I own a Ferrari worth of \euros{400000000000} (I have no idea how much that costs).
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

PS: I prefer to use `\euro{...}` instead of `\EUR{...}`. Because, the latter gives an additional spurious space which, I personally do not prefer ;)

The output with `\EUR{...}`:

[image]

Also, note that you can use just `\euro` as well.

Comment: I like \EUR{} because that way I don't have to bother about the language I'm writing in ;)

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Because \EUR{} recognizes the babel setting and sets the euro sign to the left or the right accordingly.

Comment: I don't know much about that, but it introduces an unwanted spurious space.

Comment: Sorry for raising this old question again. But with your code `\euros{1000}` does not have a separator. How does one make this work for four digits?

Comment: @E.Sommer Very nice remark! I think this deserves to be a new question. Right now I dont have a solution for that. But I will work on that.

Comment: Works well but not in `\bf` or `\textbf` mode. How could I also get bold numbers?

Comment: @Supernormal I don't know which distribution you are using. But with `pdftex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit)` I am able to render bold fonts by enclosing them as `{\bf\euros{.}}` or `\textbf{\euros{.}}` to get https://imgur.com/a/8j1TJ15.

Comment: MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{sistyle}
\SIthousandsep{,}
\newcommand{\euros}[1]{\euro{\num{#1}}}

\begin{document}
I have a 5-figure pay check with \euros{40000}.

Now I am a millionaire with \euros{4000000}.

I wish I own a Ferrari worth of \textbf{\euros{400000000000}} (I have no idea how much that costs).

I wish I own a Ferrari worth of {\bf\euros{400000000000}} (I have no idea how much that costs).
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

Combine `eurosym` with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\eur}[2][]{\EUR{\num[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\eur{10000}

\eur[group-separator={,}]{10000}

\sisetup{group-separator={,}}

\eur{10000}

\end{document}
```

A particular option for number formatting can be passed as optional argument or set by default with `\sisetup`.

[image]

The same but with `\usepackage[right]{eurosym}`:

[image]